# changing a arrays inside loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm trying write the program to read the file and copy needed phrases. Exemplary file looks that:

```
name                    =   magic_ring;

mainflag                =   magic;
flags                   =   ring;

value                   =   600;
```

In one of the files there is more than one object like that. My idea is to read every character separately and remove all the white spaces. After that I;m gonna  "glue" the characters into one string. Second step is finding position of "=" by myString.find("=") and copying all characters after "=" until the program will see ";". Copied characters are saved in new array named "name", "mainflag", "flags", "value" etc. Its works, but the problem is that I have to write as many loops as many there are arrays. Does exist any way to changing array in situation like that? It's my the fragment of my code:

```
for (int index= 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        size_t pos = myString.find("=");
        arrayChar[pos] = '\0'; //removing "=" from this line

        for(int i = 0; arrayChar[i] != ';'; i++)
            mainflag[index] = mainflag[index] + mainflag[i];
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What structure/object do you want to have at the end?

Comment: why not use an existing configuration file library (that supports the ini format), like [boost program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/program_options.html)

Comment: I don't understand at all your question...